# Django-polymorphic models having issues making migrations on 1.7

Tags: django, makemigrations

I am using Django 1.7 and django-polymorphic for my models

```
class ReferenceItem(PolymorphicModel):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'), auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_('date modified'), auto_now=True, db_index=True)
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class OrderItem(ReferenceItem):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', related_name='items')
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    tax_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    commission_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
```

When I ran `makemigrations` I got this error:

```
raise InvalidBasesError("Cannot resolve bases for %r\nThis can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)\n in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more" % new_unrendered_models)
django.db.migrations.state.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'orders.OrderItem'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
```

I have been through the django [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22708) but still unaware what the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with polymorphic package I guess.

What I have done to fix it is to comment out my apps, leaving the builtin django apps, run `./manage.py migrate` to migrate the system apps, then uncomment my apps, and run `./manage.py makemigrations`

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this:

1) Add a `migrations` directory to the problematic app (`orders` in this case).

```
mkdir /path/to/your/app/migrations
```

2) Add an `__init__.py` to that same migrations directory.

```
touch /path/to/your/app/migrations/__init__.py
```

3) Run `python manage.py makemigrations <yourapp>`

4) Migrate any other apps, individually or as a whole, if you are fortunate.

And that should solve it. It's less error prone and hacky than depending on commenting out any installed apps, which isn't really consistent or reproducible.