# InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'users.GroupProxy'>]

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, django-migrations

When I run tests I get this error during database initialization:

```
django.db.migrations.state.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'users.GroupProxy'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
```

I created this proxy for contrib.auth Group model to place it in my app in django admin:

```
class GroupProxy(Group):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = Group._meta.verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = Group._meta.verbose_name_plural
```

So what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @Dimitry Mikhaylov did you solve this issue ? I'm also facing the exact same error for the proxy I've set. I'd be glad if you can help me.

Comment: I had to run migrations for `contrib.auth` before, it didn't work otherwise.

Comment: You may need to create a migrations folder with an empty __init__.py in it so Django can actually create the migration file.  See the answer by Tamriel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261030/migration-error-with-django-1-7-1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After a lot of digging on this the only thing that worked for me was

`comment out the offending apps, run migrations, then add them in again.`

Just a workaround but hopefully it helps somebody.

Comment: just add a folder named "migrations" and in it create "__init__.py" file.

Comment: do u mean commenting them out from INSTALLED_APPS?

Answer (score 34):

Simply creating a `migrations` directory at the root of your app (so `users/migrations/` in your case) and  adding an empty `__init__.py` file might resolve your issue.  At least it did for me when I was getting the same error.

But you're better off running `makemigrations` for your app, as suggested by 
@zenofewords above.  That will create the directory for you AND generate migrations for your proxy models.

[Why does Django create migration files for proxy models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988914/why-does-django-create-migration-files-for-proxy-models)

Your tests are looking for those migrations and aren't finding them.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 24):

I've come across this issue, and as commenting out the model isn't really a solution, I've found that setting the undocumented `auto_created = True` to the Meta class will make Django ignore it.

```
class GroupProxy(Group):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        auto_created = True
```

Comment: This will cause problems when creating the permissions for those apps though, so use it with care

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried running `manage.py makemigrations <app_label>` on your app before running tests?

Also, check if the app which model(s) you are trying to Proxy is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: when you run `python manage.py test` it will try to create test DB and apply all migrations before running tests.

Comment: I already had a database, but was missing the migrations files.  After I did this (`makemigrations <app>`), I got errors that the `app_name.model_name table already exists` I solved this by editing the migration file (`app/migrations/0001_initial.py`) and commenting out every line in the `operations = [...]` list.

Answer (score 7):

add a folder named "`migrations`" and in this folder create "`__init__.py`" file

Answer (score 6):

Having spent the majority of this afternoon trying to solve this error myself, going through every conceivable mixture of 'commenting out apps', 'dropping tables' and dropping entire databases I found that my issue was caused by a simple lack of a 'migrations' folder and an __ init__.py file inside of said folder.

**One of the older answers which was correct is now no longer correct as they have fixed the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3513#issuecomment-98353642).**

Check every directory that contains the model mentioned in 'init.py' and it should go away.

Probably won't solve everyone's case but it helped mine.

Comment: run makemigrations for all the apps that you are using.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced this issue (after doing some complex model inheritance). One of my migrations contained

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='Offer',
    fields=[
        # ...
    ],
    options={
        # ...
    },
    bases=('shop.entity',),
),
```

I deleted `shop.Entity` model entirely, but the migration was referencing it in `bases` attribute. So I just deleted `bases=('shop.entity',)` and it works. It will probably break an opportunity to migrate from the beginning, but at least allows to migrate further on.

Another advice would be: go directly to django code and inspect what's causing "bases" trouble. Go to `django/db/migrations/state.py` and add a breakpoint:

```
try:
    bases = tuple(
        (apps.get_model(base) if isinstance(base, six.string_types) else base)
        for base in self.bases
    )
except LookupError:
    print(self.bases)  # <-- print the bases
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()  # <-- debug here
    raise InvalidBasesError("Cannot resolve one or more bases from %r" % (self.bases,))
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem after I renamed the parent table of a bunch of my proxy models. I resolved it by:

1. Deleting the migration file that had the name change for the parent table.
2. Using the postgres terminal, I renamed the parent table to its previous name.
3. Ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` again

Answer (score 0):

If this is only happening when running `python manage.py test` (maybe because you have already made the necessary migrations), you should explicitly say that `contrib.auth` should not migrate in the `MIGRATION_MODULES` of your settings module.

```
MIGRATION_MODULES(
        'auth': "contrib.auth.migrations_not_used_in_tests",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the deleting or creating of a model in the migration file is in the wrong order. I experienced this in Django 1.7.8 when the base model was BEFORE the derived model. Swapping the order for deleting the model fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

happened to me with no other app - just because I renamed a model which was a base for other models (and maybe created that sub-models within the same migration) renaming the super-model to it's original name solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and adding `app_label` attribute in `class Meta:` solved the error :

```
class GroupProxy(Group):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = '<app in which you want this model>'
        verbose_name = Group._meta.verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = Group._meta.verbose_name_plural
```

Answer (score 0):

If this occurs to you in an app that already has a migrations folder (and a **init**.py file in it), delete all other files, and run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.

P.S.: You may need to reconfigure your models.py or some tables in your database manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone made the same mistake as me, I had the same issue because I hadn't made any migrations for the Proxy models.  It didn't seem necessary to me as they don't have their own DB tables and I didn't see anything mentioning this in the docs. `python manage.py makemigrations <APP_NAME>` fixed it right up.

Answer (score 0):

There's a related question. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67500550/502045

TL;DR

Create your own operation to remove bases

```py
class RemoveModelBasesOptions(ModelOptionOperation):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def deconstruct(self):
        kwargs = {
            'name': self.name,
        }
        return (
            self.__class__.__qualname__,
            [],
            kwargs
        )

    def state_forwards(self, app_label, state):
        model_state = state.models[app_label, self.name_lower]
        model_state.bases = (models.Model,)
        state.reload_model(app_label, self.name_lower, delay=True)

    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state,
                          to_state):
        pass

    def database_backwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state,
                           to_state):
        pass

    def describe(self):
        return "Remove bases from the model %s" % self.name

    @property
    def migration_name_fragment(self):
        return 'remove_%s_bases' % self.name_lower
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run `makemigrations` for the apps without migrations.

In my case `django_quiz` depends on `multichoice`, `true_false` and `essay`.

I had to `makemigrations` for each of these before I could `migrate` django_quiz.

Answer (score 0):

I think in my case, I just deleted the parent model inherited by the child model, let us I have ***CustomUser*** model and Inherited by ***Employee*** model, Before I deleted the employee migration, I was in error same with yours, But After I deleted it worked

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for proxy models as well. I had a model `A` and a proxy model `B`. For some decisions I had to refactor the name of model `A` to model `C`, then when I run the migrations nothing worked. The reason is the next:

- When you create your migrations using `manage.py makemigrations` on a proxy model the migration file is something like this:

```py
 migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BProxy',
            fields=[
            ],
            options={
                'proxy': True,
                'indexes': [],
                'constraints': [],
            },
           bases=('app_name.database_table_name_of_a',),
        ),
```

[more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988914/why-does-django-create-migration-files-for-proxy-models).
If you see the `bases` line doesn't refer to the python model but the database table, so in *my case* that created and issue . So the solution:

1. Create and empty migration and delete the proxy model

```py
operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='PythonProxyModelClassName',
        ),
```

2. Run again `python manage.py makemigrations`.

This have the advantage of keeping your migrations history clean so if you are working on different environments it will be easier to maintain them.

*disclaimer*: I haven't manually check if the `permissions` model configuration gets affected by this, but after running tests with database construction it seams it doesn´t.