# Why does Django create migration files for proxy models?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, proxy-classes

I just created a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) and was surprised that `manage.py makemigrations` creates a new migration file with a `migrations.CreateModel` operation.

A proxy model does not create a new database table, it's just a different python interface to the same dataset and indeed `manage.py sqlmigrate my_app_label 0042` returns nothing.

I thought that it might be used to create the proxy model `ContentType` but those are created on demand if they don't exist.

Is it used to trigger the creation of the proxy model permissions? There's a [6 year old open bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154) on proxy model permissions so I'm not really sure how this part is supposed to work now...

It used `Django 1.8` to test this.

**Edit**: to clarify, `Django` creates a migration that does nothing for new proxy models so wouldn't we want `Django` to not create the migration in the first place if it's of no use?

Is there a use case where it would be useful to have the migration?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ah, but if you open the migration in your editor, you will find that it's actually an empty migration! Here is an example

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('stackoverflow', '0009_auto_20160622_1507'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyArticle',
            fields=[
            ],
            options={
                'proxy': True,
            },
            bases=('stackoverflow.article',),
        ),
    ]
```

And if you run `./manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0010` (which is the number that corresponds to my migration above), what you get is what's on the next line (nothing).

This is because the `fields` section of the migration is empty and `option` includes `proxy = True`. This setting prevents any `SQL` from being executed for this migration, and the original table is left untouched.

So you may ask, why does `Django` bother to create an empty migration? That's because the proxy model may be referred to by another model in a future migration.

Answer (score 8):

I believe `migrations` are generated because the databases is affected and `migrations` are how Django signals database changes.  The structure is not changed, but entries are added in (at least) two tables:

- A new `ContentType` is added to `django_content_type` for the proxy model.
- Permissions specific to the Proxy Model are added to `auth_permission`.  I assume this "always" happens unless the proxy uses the exact same class name.  It certainly does happen -- we actually use a proxy model to access User using different permissions without touching the default User model.

Both of these details are actually noted in the comment chain of the issue linked by the OP (e.g. comment #31) because they contribute to the bug (i.e. that Django looks for permissions in a different app than those actually generated in `auth_permissions`).